# Trouble Swip to blank

Tags: css, swipe

I hope you can help me. I use swiper, where swiper contains picture and if swip change to picture 2 then i click next should return to picture 1 (back to start). The problem I face is when the swip does not return to image 1 but returns the empty slide and then back to the beginning. Here I attach the coding and image results.

[image: Swip 1 is picture and to swipe to]
[image: Swip 3 blank must be back to swip1]
[Script](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzdsYVbUDYRhMUp1SzJYbDJ1UGc)

```
  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        slidesPerView: 1,
        paginationClickable: true,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        loop: true
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: It may help if you include your HTML and CSS so that we can fully reproduce the issue.

Comment: @showdev I've attached the coding on the attachment file named script.